# Android bluetooth IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, kotlin

I have a problem with connecting my client socket in the Android bluetooth API.
I already read these posts: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657427/ioexception-read-failed-socket-might-closed-bluetooth-on-android-4-3?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357306/getting-java-io-ioexception-read-failed-socket-might-closed-or-timeout-read-r), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776712/android-connect-bluetooth-device-automatically-after-pairing-programmatically) and [this one](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth)
According to these posts I made my code like the following but it still not work:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    private val bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
    private var connectThread: ConnectThread? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (bluetoothAdapter != null)
        {
            if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled)
                bluetoothAdapter.enable()

            val devices = bluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices.toTypedArray()


            if (devices.isNotEmpty())
            {
                connectThread = ConnectThread(devices[0])
                connectThread!!.run()
            }
        }
        else
            Log.i("BluetoothTest", "No bluetooth supported")
    }

    override fun onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy()

        connectThread!!.cancel()
    }

    private inner class ConnectThread(device: BluetoothDevice) : Thread()
    {
        //private val socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString ("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"))
        private val socket = device.javaClass.getMethod("createRfcommSocket", (Int::class
            .javaPrimitiveType)).invoke(device, 2) as BluetoothSocket

        override fun run()
        {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery()
            socket.connect()
        }

        fun cancel()
        {
            socket.close()
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the logs with the returned error that comes on socket.connect():

```
--------- beginning of crash
05-15 15:59:19.553 24176-24176/com.bluetoothtest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.bluetoothtest, PID: 24176
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bluetoothtest/com.bluetoothtest.MainActivity}: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:685)
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:697)
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:374)
    at com.bluetoothtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:36)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
```

It seems that the problem appeared after Android 4.3 because of the port value of the socket
I am on Android 7.1 and 8.1
Does someone knows how to make bluetooth work on Android ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, the root cause was because the socket's inputStream couldn't be read. That's because there was no open socket **with the same UUID** on the server side.

See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-8.0.0_r30/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.java

So to fix the problem we need a listening socket with the same UUID on the other side, for me it was a raspberry in python:

```
from bluetooth import *

server_sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

port = server_sock.getsockname()[1]

uuid = "YOUR UUID"

advertise_service( server_sock, "SampleServer", service_id = uuid, service_classes = [ uuid, SERIAL_PORT_CLASS ], profiles = [ SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ])

print("Waiting for connection on RFCOMM channel %d" % port)

client_sock, client_info = server_sock.accept()
print("Accepted connection from ", client_info)

try:
    while True:
        data = client_sock.recv(1024)
        if len(data) == 0: break
        print("received [%s]" % data)
except IOError:
    pass

print("disconnected")

client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
print("all done")
```

from https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/master/examples/simple/rfcomm-server.py